# Refresh python process multiple times within a test in pytest

Tags: python, process, pytest, random-seed

I have an interesting use case, where I have values that are inserted into an array in a random order. I then generate the hash of this array (using hashlib). Now, I want to make sure that this hash is always the same between different runs, so I am sorting this array before I hash it, and that solves the problem perfectly. (Note: this is an abstraction of the problem. It's not exactly like that, so replacing arrays by sets, or similar solutions are not what I'm looking for here).

Now, here is where my actual problem is: To prevent regressions, I want to add a test that reruns the process multiple times and ensures that the hash is the same between all those runs. The problem is, there is no way to rerun that process multiple times within the unit test. If I rerun it, the random order will always be the same (maybe because a random seed is being reused or something), negating the value of the test in the first place.

Thus, is there a way to run the test multiple times with a totally fresh Python process, in order to compare the outputs of the runs of the test, and make sure they are equal?

Answer (score 0):

We were finally able to solve the problem with this:

```
import multiprocessing


def _generate_hash(queue: Queue):
    // execute the hash generation process


def test_hash_is_consistent_across_multiple_runs():
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=_generate_hash, args=(q))
        p.start()
        p.join()

    previous_hash = None
    for i in range(5):
        current_hash = q.get()
        if previous_hash:
            assert current_hash == previous_hash
        previous_hash = current_hash
```

The trick is by using `spawn`, which will create a fresh python process for each created process.